# How to write reccursion method for following data

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion

Hi my database structure  is like

```
Id  ParentId    MenuName    URL
1   0           Home            google.com
2   1           Privacy         yahoo.com
3   0           About Us    gmail.com
4   0           Contact US  www.contactus.com
5   2           Disclaimer  www.disclaimer.com
6   4           FeedBack    www.feedback.com
7   3           What we do  www.whatwedo.com
8   3           How we do   www.howWeDo.com
```

I would like to get data based on parentid. Main problem is that data can be N level deep. Need solution in C# or in LINQ

Thanks

Tried so far:

```
 public string getMenuItems(int parentId)
{

    using (dynamicMenuEntities context = new dynamicMenuEntities())
    {
        var menuObj = from r in context.Menus
                      where r.ParentId == parentId
                      select new { r.MenuName, r.URL, r.Id };


        foreach (var obj in menuObj)
        {
            sbMenu.Append("<li><a target=\"_blank\" href='" + Page.ResolveUrl(obj.URL) + "'>" + obj.MenuName + "</a></li>");
            int childCount = context.Menus.Count(ch => ch.ParentId == obj.Id);
            if (childCount > 0)
            {
                return getMenuItems(obj.Id);
            }
        }
        return sbMenu.ToString();


    }
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: If I were you, for this type of data, I'd get the whole lot, then use a recursive LINQ function to sort it into an object. This object, for example `LinkItem` can have an `IEnumerable<LinkItem>` under it, which you can fill with it's children by using a recursive method

Comment: Hi Daniel Thats what i am asking how to write recursion method ???

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exact answer to your question but:

If you want Parent/Child relation ship, in database you must have a self relationship like this:

[image]

And EF will generate this:

[image]

And with PictureCategory1 and PictureCategory2 you can easily access to childs/parent of an item.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an entity named MenuItem in your implementation, and you are using entity framework. Then,

```
    List<MenuItem> GetMenuItemsByParentId(int parentId)
    {
    EntityContext newContext = new EntityContext();
    List<MenuItem> getMenuItems = newContext.MenuItems.Where(c => c.ParentId == parentId).ToList();
    newContext.Dispose();
    return getMenuItems;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I write this in notepad and i don't test it but you can do some think like this:
(also you can use StringBuilder instead of string)

```
public string getMenuItems(int parentId)
{
    using (dynamicMenuEntities context = new dynamicMenuEntities())
    {
        string tags = new string();
        tags += "<ul>";

        var menuObj = from r in context.Menus
                      where r.ParentId == parentId
                      select new { r.MenuName, r.URL, r.Id };


        foreach (var obj in menuObj)
        {
            tags += "<li>";

            int childCount = context.Menus.Count(ch => ch.ParentId == obj.Id);
            if (childCount > 0)
            {
                tags += obj.MenuName;
                tags += getMenuItems(obj.Id);
            }
            else
            {
                tags += "<a target=\"_blank\" href='" + Page.ResolveUrl(obj.URL) + "'>" + obj.MenuName + "</a>";
            }

            tags += "</li>"
        }

        tags += "</ul>";

        return tags;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have almost done. It is searching to nth level only problem exists is positioning of  and

tags.

```
 public string getMenuItems(int parentId)
{
    using (dynamicMenuEntities context = new dynamicMenuEntities())
    {
        var menuObj = from r in context.Menus
                      where r.ParentId == parentId
                      select new { r.MenuName, r.URL, r.Id };
        foreach (var obj in menuObj)
        {
            sbMenu.Append("<li><a target=\"_blank\" href='" + Page.ResolveUrl(obj.URL) + "'>" + obj.MenuName + "</a>");
            childCount = context.Menus.Count(r => r.ParentId == obj.Id);
            if (childCount > 0)
            {
                sbMenu.Append("<ul>");
                getMenuItems(obj.Id);
            }
            else
            {
                sbMenu.Append("</ul>");
            }

        }

    }
    return sbMenu.ToString();
}
```

HTML output(Problem is in contact us)

```
<ul id="menu"><li><a target="_blank" href='/Dynamic-HTML-Menu/www.home.com'>Home</a><ul><li><a target="_blank" href='/Dynamic-HTML-Menu/www.k.com'>Know about us</a></ul><li><a target="_blank" href='/Dynamic-HTML-Menu/www.about.com'>About</a><ul><li><a target="_blank" href='/Dynamic-HTML-Menu/www.whoweare.com'>Who we are</a></ul><li><a target="_blank" href='/Dynamic-HTML-Menu/www.contactus.com'>Contact US</a><ul><li><a target="_blank" href='/Dynamic-HTML-Menu/www.feedback.com'>FeedBack</a><ul><li><a target="_blank" href='/Dynamic-HTML-Menu/www.HellYa.com'>FeedBack2</a><ul><li><a target="_blank" href='/Dynamic-HTML-Menu/www.FeedBack3.com'>FeedBack3</a></ul><li><a target="_blank" href='/Dynamic-HTML-Menu/www.Contactus2.com'>Contact Us2</a></ul> </ul>
```

Latest data in database
[image]